# Detecting if application is accessed via SSL?

Tags: angularjs, ssl

Is there a way in Angular to detected if the application is accessed via `https` ? I need to detect that so that proper url is constructed and passed into $http service  , and passing `http` will generate `'the content must be served over HTTPS.'` errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [$window](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/service/$window) service to access an encapsulated window object :

```
if( $window.location.protocol == "https" )
{
     // whatever
}
```